# sql statement error on getting rows and

Tags: php, sql

I have a game like lottery. Normally when user register a code, that code is unique, and database should check if that code exist and if it exist should update registering the user and get the message "your code was registered"...every code can be registered only once. but I`m getting an error it says all times I try to register a code that "your code does not exist but the code is on the bank.

```
function checkCode($db,$code){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO code (code) VALUES (:code)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':code', $codex);
    $codex = $code;
    $stmt->execute();
    //enter code here
    ///// until here is ok
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM code"; 
    $result = $db->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute();
    ////here is what i think generate the error
    $number_of_rows = $result->rowCount();
    if($number_of_rows >0){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: format your code.remove stars

Comment: i inserted the stars just here to break up lines

Comment: $number_of_rows = $result->rowCount(); if($number_of_rows >0){ return true; } else{ return false; } } this line i think is the problem...but when i try to change if($number_of_rows ==1 ){ return true; } else{ return false; } }  it allows any kind of alphanumeric code to be registered, but i want to be registered only the unique codes i have in my bank row in sql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Why isn't this code working? Have you tried outputting errors? What is the exception? What isn't working? What are you getting? If the comparison doesn't behave like you want, did you see what's going in the operation?

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':code', $codex);` from your sample code it looks like $codex is not defined until the following line. Should it be `$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);`? If that's a problem, you likely aren't inserting a valid value into the DB.

Comment: Why not fetch a row? That way you know for absolute certain whether any data was returned from the query? i.e. if you issue a query then _always_ fetch the data at least one. If you only expect a few rows then just use `fetchAll` and count the array.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

`rowCount` gets the number of affected rows. A `SELECT` statement doesn't affect any rows. You should be checking the `rowCount` for `$stmt`, not `$result`.